# rendering xml documents

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout

If we have a view that has a spinner and the spinner is populated programmatically from within the application. Does the view's xml change(aka gets rendered)? if that is true how can i get the new xml for that view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the views XML does not get changed. What's displayed is dynamically computed, but the actual layout you've specified in your xml does not change.

Comment: then how can i detect whenever a gui event happend? keeping in mind i want to decrease the source code modification necessary

Comment: That's a different question and depends on what gui even you're trying to detect. Please ask a another question for that.

Comment: GUI events generated from user interactions. I asked the question 3 times but didnt get a good answer yet.